# WSO2 ESB Proxy Service Error (Transport error: 411 Error: Length Required)

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

i have a http proxyservice in wso2 esb when try this service i have an error below:

```
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope     error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 411 Error: Length      Required</TryitProxyError>
```

but when try this service in soapUI reply well ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because your backend service is expecting Content Length header.
Please add following property in your inSequence before the send mediator. Ideally this should be added before sending the message to backend.

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<inSequence>
     <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
</inSequence>
```